# How to set SPI speed for ATmega1284P?

Tags: spi

I am using MightyCore and platformio. My config file looks like [this](https://github.com/zoonman/nanodds/blob/master/platformio.ini)

My fuses are set as:

```
E:FD 
H:D6 
L:8F
```

I have controller running at 16 MHz and SCK frequency is 8 MHz.
My display is showing white color and that is it. I know to make it function properly I have to use 1 MHz SPI clocking.
If I program CKDIV8 fuse my controller doesn't start. I dunno why, kind of black magic going on there for me. My lack of knowledge is not helpful there.

I tried to use the following tricks:

Setting SPI speed using TFT library

```cpp
// earlier in main.cpp
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
// later in setup()
tft.setSPISpeed(1000000); // has no effect on SCK
```

Trying to set it directly via SPI class instance:

```cpp
// in setup()
SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV128); // no effect
```

Or statically:

```cpp
// in setup()
SPIClass::setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV128); // still no effect
```

Also I tried to pass `DEFAULT_SPI_FREQ` build flag with frequency preset.

I ran out of ideas.

Schematic is here:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: is `setSPISpeed` after `init`?

Comment: "If I program CKDIV8 fuse my controller doesn't start." How are you determining this?

Comment: @Juraj  no. It was before. I placed it after and it works now.

Comment: @timemage I have some pin manipulations later in setup() and they aren't happening.

Comment: why would you place it before? init initializes SPI and then of course sets the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-ST7735-Library/issues/107) setSPISpeed has to be made after initR like this:

```cpp
tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
tft.setSPISpeed(1000000);
```

Comment: init initializes SPI and of course sets the default value. you can change it only after that

Comment: @Juraj I have no idea what was going on in Adafruit engineers head. The display fails to init @ 8 MHz because SPI is too fast for it. It has to be initialized at 1 MHz then it supposed to function properly.